# AngularJS motivation for using netsted forms in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm trying to find a compelling reason for using nested forms in Angular.
Why should I use nested forms instead of using 1 form?
In addition regarding the ng-repeat reason which generates dynamic input directives, I can use $index to display error messages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> It is useful to nest forms, for example if the validity of a sub-group of controls needs to be determined.

[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm).

Example :
You want a shipping address to your purchase form. If the user select a "ship to my billing address" option, you're set. If he selects the "ship to another address" option, you'll need additional information to know the shipping address. You will then want to enclose the select and additional fields in a separate form whose validity will be calculated by a custom controller.

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to check validity with controller? Angular has really good validation abilities.

Comment: @VíťaPlšek-angular.cz that is actually beyond my knowledge, I've always used field based validation and was trying to get how to define form validity from the doc. If you know better please tell me and I'll edit my answer !

Comment: The main thing about separation is correct, let it be. Just for information Angular has declarative approach for templates, so also validations are declarative - they are just directives attached to input fields. Then if you have properly set validations, your fields and form gets attributes like $dirty, $invalid, $submited, and also propagate style to css classes. 
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Comment: @VíťaPlšek-angular.cz yeah but that doesn't explain how to use form validity to determine the validity of a sub-group of controls as stated in the angular doc I linked

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is validation of the nested form, ng-form helps you to separate this form entirely.

So you can have reusable form, which is directive and then ng-form let you adress its validation, without knowledge about parent form existence.

You can then use the form inside ng-repeat and adress the fields of current iteration easily. This is something which would be really hard without using ng-form. You don't want to address anything with $index.

You can see example here - http://plnkr.co/edit/9m94AuNMR8J077Cakvgb
There is form which has name and it can have multiple contacts (don't be afraid of czech validation messages)

```
<form class="form" name="ctrl.form" ng-submit="ctrl.save()" novalidate>

      <pre>form.$valid: {{ctrl.form.$valid}}</pre>
      <label>contacts list name:</label>
      <input name="name" ng-model="ctrl.contactList.name" />

      <hr />

      <fieldset class="well" ng-repeat="(index, contact) in ctrl.contactList.contacts" ng-form="nestedForm">

        <pre>
          nestedForm for contact {{index}}
          nestedForm.$valid: {{nestedForm.$valid}}</pre>

        <label>name:</label>
        <input name="contactName" type="text" ng-model="contact.name" required="" />
        <div ng-show="nestedForm.contactName.$error.required">
          Vyplňte jméno
        </div>

        <label>phone:</label>
        <input name="contactPhone" type="text" ng-model="contact.phone" required="" />
        <div ng-show="nestedForm.contactPhone.$error.required">
          Vyplňte číslo
        </div>

        <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.removeContact(index)">remove</button>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.addContact()">add</button>
      <button type="submit">Odeslat</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why you say that it is hard to use $index? just write: <div ng-show="nestedForm.['contactPhone' + $index].$error.required">

Comment: Sure and then name the fields <input name="contactPhone+{$index}"> ... So you get not very nice code for no reason. You really don't want to do that. This is hardly readable and maintainable. This is not jquery, you don't want to address structure, you want to address data. So the main thing is that contact can be treated as independent entity. In ng-repeat you also connects to 'local' variable of iteration. This is the same. The least thing is that you can check innerForm validity with nestedForm.$valid.